# Can date components be nil if explicity requesting the component?

Tags: swift, option-type, nsdatecomponents

I am wondering if it is okay to force unwrap here:

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: from, to: to)

return components.day!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is completely safe. All component properties of `DateComponents` (such as `day`, `month`, etc.) are `Optional`, since you can create `DateComponents` instances consisting of only a subset of components.

However, a `Date` object always contains all `DateComponents` and hence when you request the value of a specific component from a `Date` using `Calendar.dateComponents`, it is guaranteed to contain the requested component. So it is safe to force unwrap that component.

On the other hand, if you tried accessing a component of `DateComponents` that you didn't request with `Calendar.dateComponents`, that would be `nil`. See the example below.

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date())
components.day // 13
components.month // nil
```